# IIS Redirect rule based on multiple (but not all) conditions

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, redirect, iis-7.5

I have a rewrite that is set up to handle multiple different user agents, and I want to be able to match my rule on any of them. However, any url that matches one of these must also match another rule (an IP address). However, I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Can anyone make any suggestions on how I can do this?

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I know that this will fail because the `conditions` node has already been declared more than once.

So, in essence it's a redirect when any of the `{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` rules **and** any of the `{REMOTE_ADDR}` rules are matched.

```
<rule name="Mobile UA redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <!-- Any of these can be matched -->
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Android" />
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="BlackBerry" />
    <!-- ... more user agents... -->
  </conditions>
  <!-- Here, similarly, any one of these rules can be matched, but one of the rules above must also match one of the rules below. -->
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="192.168.0.1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://mob.mydomain.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Any help on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about smth like the following, placed at the bottom:

```
<rule name="MobileRestricted" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="192.168.0.1" negate="true" />        
  </conditions>
  <action type="None"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Mobile UA redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <!-- Any of these can be matched -->
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Android" />
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="BlackBerry" />
    <!-- ... more user agents... -->
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://mob.mydomain.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Not a single rule, but no more than two )

Comment: Hi stim, thanks for your answer. I think this could work. I see that your mobile restricted is blacklisting on IP addresses, rather than the whitelist that mine does, but it's a simple enough change to make. :)